# ValidationError: 1 validation error for SQLDatabaseToolkit llm value is not a valid dict

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, azure-openai

Trying to conenct postgresql with langchain.llm used - `AzureOpenAI`

```py
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI

llms = AzureOpenAI( temperature=0,deployment_name="gpt3turbo".......)

toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db,llm=llms)
```

Error:

```py
ValidationError: 1 validation error for SQLDatabaseToolkit
llm
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

Tried different versions of `langchain`

Comment: `SQLDatabaseToolkit` is not defined in the example code given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if all the steps are correct from the beginning.

**install packages**

```
pip install langchain 
pip install openai
pip install psycopg2
```

---

**Next create a python file called main.py and import the following**:

```
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent 
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit 
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase 
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI 
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor 
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
```

---

**Connect to database**:

```
pg_uri = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{mydatabase}"
```

Set database:

```
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(pg_uri)
```

Once you have your OPENAI_API_KEY:

```
OPENAI_API_KEY = "your OpenAI key"
```

---

Define your llm model:

```
gpt = OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo')
```

---

**Toolkit should be:**

```
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=gpt)
```

Information on Agent types : https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/

---

Credit to @DishenWang for the complete article:

https://medium.com/dataherald/how-to-connect-llm-to-sql-database-with-langchain-sqlagent-48635fddaa74